$|\Gamma(t)-\gamma(\tau_t)|<\delta$
I'm reading the proof of lemma 1.19, in general it's easy to follow, but I don't know how to justify the inequality 1.21, the one in the title, it says that is from the 1.19a, the uniform continuity, but I have the following problem to do the bounding.


For, $t_{k_1}\leq t,\tau_k \leq t_k $
$|\Gamma(t)-\gamma(\tau_t)|\leq |\Gamma(t)-\gamma(t)|+|\gamma(t)-\gamma(\tau_t)|<|\Gamma(t)-\gamma(t)|+\delta/2$
And for the other part I get
$|\Gamma(t)-\gamma(t)|=|\frac{1}{t_k-t_{k-1}}\left((t_k-t)\gamma(t_{k-1})+(t-t_{k-1})\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t)(t_k-t_{k-1})\right)|$
So, for me it's not so clear, some hint or way to see it?
